# Atomic function without locks to change two independent memory locations

Tags: c++, atomic, lock-free, compare-and-swap

I have the following function called `updateEntry` which writes a value into a lookup table. I would like to create a multi-threaded version of this function. 
I was looking into the atomic operation `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` but I am not sure how to apply it here properly.

Is it theoretical possible to implement this function atomically without locking, since it change two independent memory locations `entryLookup[id]` and `entry`?

```
   void updateEntry(Entry ** entryLookup, unsigned int id, int val1, short val2){
            Entry * entry     = entryLookup[id];
            entry->val1       = val1;
            entry->val2       = val2;
            entryLookup[id]  += sizeof(Entry);
   }
```

Comment: Questions: 1) Can you ensure each thread will access disjoint `id` set?  2) Can you ensure than modifying `val1` and  `val2`  will never affect `entryLookup` `operator[]` result? 3) Can you ensure than modifying `entryLookup` value will not affect any parallel thread (e.g. the new id is not accessed by any other thread)? If any of those rules does not match, I see difficulties to implement lock-less concurrency.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Thanks a lot for your answer. I built a solution that uses disjoint id sets but producing this disjoint sets is costly. I would like to avoid using disjoint ids sets. What do you mean by point 2.)?

Comment: Q4 - are the updates done in concur with lookups? If not, you can first atomically update `entryLookup[id]`, ensuring no other thread will use that same entry, and then update the values at your leisure (sort of). If lookups also take place, you have to update the two separate locations together, which can't be done using primitive atomic operations.

Comment: define "without locking" - you could always spin on an atomic "is-updating" flag

Comment: I do not know what `entryLookup` look like: I could imagine a class where the `operator[]` is overloaded and access `val1`. Imagine a first thread, accessing id=5, which return the entry at 0x42, after modifying val1, entryLookup now correspond to (e.g.)id=10. Next thread access id=10 which correspond also to entry at 0x42. Now both threads are accessing simultaneously the same object without lock.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I guess active polling on an atomic flag is exactly a type of lock. A lock is any synchronization between threads ensuring non-parallel access to a critical section of code.

Comment: The usual way to atomically modify a complex object is to modify a copy of it and then atomically swap in the copy, testing whether the swapped-out one is the one you expected to swap out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this thread-safe, you could increment `entryLookup[id]` first to make sure any other thread that comes later cannot change the same entry, and then fill in the values. An atomic addition is needed where the old value is returned:

```
void updateEntry(Entry ** entryLookup, unsigned int id, int val1, short val2)
{
    Entry * entry = __sync_fetch_and_add(&entryLookup[id], sizeof(Entry));
    entry->val1   = val1;
    entry->val2   = val2;
}
```

Comment: I have just noted that @eran already gave this answer in the comments.

Comment: This is simple and should solve my problem. Thanks a lot for this great answer.

Comment: @peppincsoda The problem here is that the modification of both `val` entries is never released (synchronized). How can you safely access `entry` in another thread ?

Comment: Note that this is safe only if the update phase ends before lookups as performed. Otherwise, a lookup might see an entry before its values was set. Also, as @LWimsey commented, there should be some write barrier at the end of the updates (it's likely that this kind of code will work even without explicitly requesting a flush, but accessing the values would still be considered a data race).

Comment: You are both right, I assumed that the questioner doesn't want to do lookups while updating the structure from multiple threads.